# Hide & show div(s) when viewing on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I have a div (#bob_show) that shows and another (#slider_mobile) that's hidden when open on a pc browser. I need there statement to be reversed when open on a mobile device...

Thanks a lot for your help!

Hugo

Comment: How do you wish to detect 'mobile device'? A media query will look at available sizes (screen/device width etc.), user agent will be passed as part of the request and is a lot more reliable - but is ever-changing as new devices are released.

Comment: Use Bootstrap. There is built in class which hides divs in smaller devices. As I remember it is somethimg like: hidden-xs hidden-sm (...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect the navigator type and based upon that you can do the this as desired.

for more refference visit [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery) this question.

how ever if your concern is browser width then you can go with the below technique

```
            // you can change the width condition as per your need
            if(window.matchMedia('max-width:420px').matches || $(window).width() < 768){
            // small devide
                $('#slider_mobile').show();
                $('#bob_show').hide();
            }else{
                $('#slider_mobile').hide();
                $('#bob_show').show();
            }
```